# Spring entity is being modified when nothing has changed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am using `Spring Roo` to create a simple Web application with user management. I have an `AppUser` entity with (among others) a `password` field which when updating other attributes of the entity is being set to null even though I haven't changed it at all.

To implement the use case of updating an `AppUser`'s instance, `Roo` generated two methods `updateForm` and `update`.

The former method prepares the form for editing the entity:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", produces = "text/html")
public String updateForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel) {
    AppUser appUser = AppUser.findAppUser(id);
    populateEditForm(uiModel, appUser);
    System.out.println("On Update Form - " + appUser);
    return "users/update";
}
```

The second method checks for validation errors and merges the entity into the JPA context:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
public String update(@Valid AppUser appUser, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    System.out.println("On Update - " + appUser);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, appUser);
        return "users/update";
    }
    uiModel.asMap().clear();
    appUser.merge();
    return "redirect:/users/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(appUser.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
}
```

The default value of the `password` field in the edit form is blank, but on it's mutator method `setPassword`, I am not updating password when null or blank is sent.

```
public void setPassword(String password) {
    // Don't update password if null or blank is sent
    if (password != null && !password.isEmpty()) {
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encodePassword(password, null);
        this.password = encodedPassword;
    }
}
```

The outcome in the standard output is the following:

```
On Update Form - AppUser[username=user,password=04f8996da763b7a969b1028ee3007569eaf3a635486ddab211d512c85b9df8fb,enabled=true,appRole=AppRole[rolename=ROLE_USER,id=2,version=1],customer=Customer[code=<null>,description=default,address=<null>,cap=<null>,locality=<null>,province=<null>,telephone=<null>,fax=<null>,vat=<null>,fiscalCode=<null>,sex=<null>,customerType=<null>,insertionDate=<null>,lastVisit=<null>,id=0,version=<null>],id=2,version=0]

On Update - AppUser[username=user,password=<null>,enabled=true,appRole=AppRole[rolename=ROLE_USER,id=2,version=1],customer=Customer[code=<null>,description=default,address=<null>,cap=<null>,locality=<null>,province=<null>,telephone=<null>,fax=<null>,vat=<null>,fiscalCode=<null>,sex=<null>,customerType=<null>,insertionDate=<null>,lastVisit=<null>,id=0,version=<null>],id=2,version=0]
```

Evidently the password is being changed, but I can't understand where.

**Edit:**

The jspx view I'm using to update the AppUser information is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <form:update id="fu_it_digitelematica_leovince_domain_AppUser" modelAttribute="appUser" path="/users" versionField="Version" z="9/aOTZ+wTF1ijLMgiWkx1JcbpG8=">
        <field:input field="username" id="c_it_digitelematica_leovince_domain_AppUser_username" required="true" z="H3JOKuXes6/RLOnAd4x1v0j3Njo="/>
        <field:input field="password" id="c_it_digitelematica_leovince_domain_AppUser_password" required="false" type="password" z="user-managed"/>
        <field:checkbox field="enabled" id="c_it_digitelematica_leovince_domain_AppUser_enabled" z="4WIlYpFXs46FLp4l8koJ2DXmWz8="/>
        <field:select field="appRole" id="c_it_digitelematica_leovince_domain_AppUser_appRole" itemValue="id" items="${approles}" path="/approles" required="true" z="KDeZRlxip/VWLtb/kN58hn2zZdg="/>
        <field:select field="customer" id="c_it_digitelematica_leovince_domain_AppUser_customer" itemValue="id" items="${customers}" path="/customers" required="true" z="rEMR1CzjRLuSkoIKTHmq4N+qZoI="/>
    </form:update>
</div>
```

Comment: Which jspx view are you using to update Entity information? Could you provide us that jspx view code?

Comment: Please find at the end of the question the code of the jspx view to update AppUser information.

Comment: This seems to be related with the known issue of using unconfigured the Spring's DataBinder http://support.springsource.com/security/spring-mvc however it still doesn't explain why the password property is being changed.

Comment: Did you try to remove "type=password" attribute from your field:input? Maybe, there's an error on input.tagx... Could you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard way: When you merge a entity you *override all its values*. Let me explain:

1. RequestHandler creates a new *user* instance and fill it with request values
2. You *attach* the instance to a *entityManager* which store it in DB.

On point #2 ***entityManager* doesn't know anything about Request** and it's values, so, when you *merge* the user, **if `password` field is `null` that will be the new value** for field on DB. This is why Spring Roo generated views includes all fields in update form.

To solve this problem you must load an *attached* instance of entity and fill the missing values of *binding* instance (*warning, not tested code*):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
public String update(@Valid AppUser appUser, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    System.out.println("On Update - " + appUser);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, appUser);
        return "users/update";
    }
    uiModel.asMap().clear();
    User attached = User.findUserById(user.getId());
    appUser.setPassword_encoded(attached..getPassword());
    appUser.merge();
    return "redirect:/users/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(appUser.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
}
```

You need a mutator which set password without encode it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed it is a completely new AppUser instance initialized with the request parameters. For some reason I thought it would be the same instance but with the attributes which changed bound to it. Now I understand I need some custom logic to handle partial updates as I'm needing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove "type=password" attribute from your field:input?

Maybe, there's an error on input.tagx... Could you try it?

If you detect as error you can create an issue on http://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the result was the same. Inspecting input.tagx source code I saw the main difference is that in one case it uses Spring's input tag and in the other it uses the password tag. Using the latest, the input is an HTML password field and no default value is provided.